# Can the Sudden Charge and Shielded Stride feats be used together?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, fighter, action-economy

Can the Sudden Charge and Shielded Stride feats be used together?

The description of the [Sudden Charge](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=134) feat says:

> Two actions

> With a quick sprint, you dash up to your foe and swing. Stride twice. If you end your movement within melee reach of at least one enemy, you can make a melee Strike against that enemy.

The description of the [Shielded Stride](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=375) feat says:

> When your shield is up, your enemies' blows can't touch you. When you have your shield raised, you can Stride to move half your Speed without triggering reactions that are triggered by your movement (such as Attacks of Opportunity).

It looks like Shielded Stride is not an action, but instead a feat that modifies the Stride action when you have your shield raised. The Sudden Charge action has Stride as a subordinate action.

So if you have both feats, could you:

1. Raise Shield
2. Use Sudden Charge

   - Stride once at half distance
   - Stride a second time at half distance
   - Strike

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### They can be used together.

As you noticed, Shielded Stride doesn't grant you a new action, it specifically modifies your Strides (and your Swims and Flies too if you have the corresponding movement speeds).

If the intent was to make that not-compatible, Shielded Strike could have easily have been formulated like:

> When you have your shield raised, you can use an action to Stride half your speed without triggering reactions that are triggered by your movement.

Or it could even have the little "one action" symbol. As there is none of that there is no reason to think this modification of Strides can't apply to the ones granted by Sudden Charge.

Also, charging through a crowd with your shield raised to catch a specific target is definitely a flavor win if you ask me.

Comment: And if the intent was to be compatible, it should have been phrased "When you stride with your shield raised, ...". Still, I think you're right based on the lack of symbol, and based on the wording of the last sentence of Shielded Stride.

Comment: @ikegami This other formulation would mean you *have* to use this effect any time you Stride with a shield raised. The actual formulation makes it optional (which is good)

Comment: Not so, "...you may...

Comment: @ikegami But then you'd have a very clunky formulation that looks like it's from DnD: "when you stride with your shield raised, you may choose to reduce your speed by half to make this movement not trigger reactions". And then you'd get all the weirdness because someone somewhere has an ability that prevents speed reductions. Not saying it isn't possible to make something that works by wording the way you suggest, but that is also has its downsides.

Comment: Re "*And then you'd get all the weirdness because someone somewhere has an ability that prevents speed reductions*", That's not relevant. Nothing about the current (ambiguous and confusing) wording avoids that either. General rule for this is restrictions trump permissions ("can't trumps can").

Comment: @ikegami It does: the current wording doesn't involve a speed reduction, it just lets you use Stride to do something different ("move half your speed without triggering" instead of "move your speed"). That is a choice you can make anytime you would stride as long as you meet the prerequisites (having a shield raised) and there isn't something that prevents it (afaik there is no such thing in the game). That alternate wording just isn't what one who is used to PF2 would expect to see.

Comment: Re "*it just lets you use Stride...*", No, it doesn't actually say that. That's the problem. It's what it means, yes. But it's not what it says. /// Re "*... to do something different*", Yes, what you just called a speed reduction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145322/discussion-between-anne-aunyme-and-ikegami).